# Importing non-standard csv file

Tags: excel, csv, import, powerquery

I am tasked with importing multiple csv files into a single excel file.
Seems easy right...

Well there's a curve ball.

The csv are not the standard row of column headings and then rows of data.
They are more:
column heading, value
column heading, value

Transpose the table no problem right....
Well here's the second curve ball.
column heading a, value a
column heading b, value b
column heading c, value c, heading c2, value c2
column heading d, value d, heading d2, value d2

[Screenshot of File 1 imported to excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGLDe.jpg)
(Note the highlighted area.)

What I need to end up with is:

Column heading a, Heading b, Heading c, Heading c2, Heading d, Heading d2
value a, value b, value c, value c2, value d, value d2

[Screen shot of file 1 data manipulated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVE0P.jpg)

I'm using Excel and power query but I'm not sure how to clean this up.

**file1.csv**

```
File Name,iqt csv file.csv,,,<br>
,Date File Extracted,10/7/2016 10:07,,<br>
Software Version,V215,,,<br>
,,,,<br>
Turns,0.244,,,<br>
Close Torque,Rated,,,<br>
Open Torque,Rated,,,<br>
Open On,LIMIT,,,<br>
Close On,LIMIT,,,<br>
Close Direction,CLOCKWISE,,,<br>
Power Loss Inhibit,OFF,,,<br>
Interrupter Timer,OFF,,,<br>
Conditional Control,OFF,,,<br>
1 Sec Control,OFF,,,<br>
5% Boost,OFF,,,<br>
ESD Mode,STATIONARY,,,<br>
ESD Signal,ACTIVE LOW,,,<br>
ESD Tstat Bypass,OFF,,,<br>
ESD Interlock Bypass,ON,,,<br>
ESD Local Stop Bypass,OFF,,,<br>
ESD Interrupter Timer Override,OFF,,,<br>
Remote Source,BOTH,,,<br>
Two Wire Control Priority,STATIONARY,,,<br>
Power Supply,SINGLE PHASE MAINS,,,<br>
Local Control,SELF MAINTAINED,,,<br>
S1,Contact,NO,Trip On,CLOSE END POSITION<br>
S2,,NO,,OPEN END POSITION<br>
S3,,NC,,CLOSE END POSITION<br>
S4,,NC,,OPEN END POSITION<br>
S5,,NO,,CLOSE END POSITION<br>
S6,,NO,,OPEN END POSITION<br>
S7,,NO,,TORQUE TRIP ANY POSITION<br>
S8,,NO,,REMOTE SELECTED<br>
LED Close Colour,GREEN,,,<br>
LED Mid Travel Indication,ON,,,<br>
CPT (If fitted),20mA,OPEN,4mA,CLOSED<br>
Partial Stroke Feature,DISABLED,,,<br>
Fetterolf,DISABLED,,,<br>
 ,,,,<br>
Option Fitted,PROFIBUS,,,<br>
Action on Loss of Comms,,,,<br>
Off,,,,<br>
Limited Range Position Minimum,0,%,,<br>
Limited Range Position Maximum,0,%,,<br>
Deadband,0,%,,<br>
Motion Inhibit Time,0,s,,<br>
Address Change,TRUE,,,<br>
Address,0,,,<br>
Auxilliary Inputs,,,,<br>
Aux 1,Report 1 for o/c,,,<br>
Aux 2,Report 1 for o/c,,,<br>
Aux 3,Report 1 for o/c,,,<br>
Aux 4,Report 1 for o/c,,,<br>
Signal Loss Timeout,0,s,,<br>
Manufacturing Data,,,,<br>
Serial Number,B412510101,,,<br>
Wiring Diagram,WD19595-01,,,<br>
Type & Size,IQTM250,,,<br>
Base,FA10,,,<br>
Enclosure,30,,,<br>
Voltage,WT,,,<br>
Month/Year,480360,,,<br>
Speed,209,,,<br>
Test Rig,RF1,,,<br>
Operator Notes,,,,<br>
,.....................,,,<br>
,....................,,,<br>
```

**file2.csv**

```
"File Name","iqtConfigCSVFileBlank.csv"<br>
"","Date File Extracted","10/10/2016 9:16:27 AM "<br>
<br>
<br>
"Turns",0<br>
"Close Torque %",40<br>
"Open Torque %",40<br>
"Open On","TORQUE"<br>
"Close On","TORQUE"<br>
"Close Direction","CLOCKWISE"<br>
"Power Loss Inhibit","ON"<br>
"Interrupter Timer","OFF"<br>
"Conditional Control","OFF"<br>
"1 Sec Control","OFF"<br>
"5% Boost","OFF"<br>
"ESD Mode","CLOSE"<br>
"ESD Signal","ACTIVE LOW"<br>
"ESD Tstat Bypass","OFF"<br>
"ESD Interlock Bypass","OFF"<br>
"ESD Local Stop Bypass","OFF"<br>
"ESD Interrupter Timer Override","OFF"<br>
"Remote Source","OFF"<br>
"Two Wire Control Priority","CLOSE"<br>
"Power Supply","3 PHASE MAINS"<br>
"Local Control","SELF MAINTAINED"<br>
"S1","Contact","NC","Trip On","INTERMEDIATE POSITION",50,"%"<br>
"S2","","NC","","INTERMEDIATE POSITION",50,"%"<br>
"S3","","NC","","INTERMEDIATE POSITION",50,"%"<br>
"S4","","NC","","INTERMEDIATE POSITION",50,"%"<br>
"LED Close Colour","GREEN"<br>
"CPT (If fitted)","20mA","OPEN","4mA","CLOSED"<br>
"Partial Stroke Feature","DISABLED"<br>
"Fetterolf","DISABLED"<br>
" "<br>
"Manufacturing Data"<br>
"Operator Notes"<br>
"NO USER NOTE FITTED"<br>
<br>
<br>
```

Thanks for looking.

Comment: I cant make any sense of your description of your requirements vs the files.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the file sample content you provided it looks fairly standard.  It loaded automatically for me without any major issues - just filter or remove the first heading rows and rename the data columns.

Comment: This probably should be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: There were 3 sentences in my original answer.  OK the first should be a comment, I've moved it into a comment.  The other 2 sentences are my answer to the question.  I have taken the sample data from the question and tested it using Power Query.